# Who is creating the _Layout.cshtml

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, castle-windsor

I'm using a `IDependencyResolver` implementation for Windsor with a custom `WebViewPage` that has a service as a property (assume a logging service) all within a MVC3 project.

The service is injected in all views (their creation passes trough the `IDependencyResolver`).

The problem is that in the _Layout.cshtml (the layout) the service remains null.

So the question is who is creating the layout since it is not created by the `IDependencyResolver` (or maybe I'm just missing the obvious)?

**Edit:**

```
public abstract class WebViewPage<TModel> : System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<TModel>
{
    public ILocalizer Localizer { get; set; }
}
```

then

```
<pages pageBaseType="[full namespace].WebViewPage">
```

in both system.web.webPages.razor and system.web section in the web.config from ~/Views
and finally the dependency resolver:

```
public class WindsorDependencyResolver : IDependencyResolver
{
    private readonly IKernel kernel;

    public WindsorDependencyResolver(IKernel kernel)
    {
        this.kernel = kernel;
    }

    public object GetService(Type serviceType)
    {
        return kernel.HasComponent(serviceType) ? kernel.Resolve(serviceType) : RegisterAndResolve(serviceType);
    }

    public IEnumerable<object> GetServices(Type serviceType)
    {
        return kernel.HasComponent(serviceType) ? kernel.ResolveAll(serviceType).Cast<object>() : new object[] { };
    }

    private object RegisterAndResolve(Type serviceType)
    {
        if (!serviceType.IsAbstract && !serviceType.IsInterface)
        {
            kernel.Register(Component.For(serviceType).ImplementedBy(serviceType).LifestylePerWebRequest());
            return kernel.Resolve(serviceType);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

The dependency resolver is set in Global.asax.cs:

```
var dependencyResolver = new WindsorDependencyResolver(container.Kernel);
DependencyResolver.SetResolver(dependencyResolver);
```

When any view is instantiated (Index.cshtml) the GetService method from the dependency resolver is called and the view is created by the container. For the _Layout.cshtml that method is not called.

So when I do this in Index.cshtml: `@Localizer.Localize(....)` the localizaer service is not null but in _Layout.cshtml it is `null`, the concrete problem being I can't localize anything in the view (and I don't want to have a view for each supported locale).

I hope it is more clear now.

**Edit:**
Still no clear answer on this one...
I didn't have the time to check the MVC sources but the answer must be there for sure...

Comment: Why are you trying to get your service in your views?

Comment: A better example will be a localization service of some kind.

Comment: I'm encountering the same issue. Did you have any luck on figuring this out?

Answer (score 1):

It's created by the Razor view engine. It's base type is defined inside the `~/views/web.config` in the `pageBaseType` attribute of the `pages` node. By default it is `System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage`.

If you wanted to do dependency injection into your Razor templates (no matter if is _Layout or some other view) you could define your custom page base type:

```
public abstract class MyWebViewPage<T> : WebViewPage<T>
{
    public MyWebViewPage()
    {
        SomeDependency = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IFoo>();
    }

    public IFoo SomeDependency { get; private set; }
}
```

then in `~/views/web.config` you set the base type:

```
<pages pageBaseType="AppName.Controllers.MyWebViewPage">
```

and then all your templates will have the `SomeDependency` property available:

```
@model MyViewModel
@SomeDependency.FooBar()
```

Notice though that this might not be a good design choice in some situations. If you intend to inject some custom HTML helper to your view then it is OK. But if you intend to inject some domain service and have your views start fetching dependencies from left and right instead of using view models, then you are doing a serious design mistake because a view's responsibility is not to fetch dependencies. Its responsibility is to display the information that it is passed under the form of a view model. Where this information comes from is not the view responsibility. It is the controller to coordinate the fetching of the data and putting it into the view model that is passed to the view.

Comment: That is exactly what I'm doing. And the issue is i can call @Localizer (as in the example) in every view but in the _Layout.cshtml (where it is null).

Comment: @Padel, I am unable to reproduce the issue. Did you notice in my example how the dependency is fetched in the `MyWebViewPage` constructor using the dependency resolver? That's called the service locator pattern. It is considered as anti-pattern by some purists compared to dependency injection but that's your only hope with Razor. Probably in future versions of the engine they will provide to use real dependency injection.

Comment: Everything is implemented as above with one exception: you don't call the dependency resolver explicitly. The dependency resolver plugs the IoC container (i.e. Windsor) into MVC architecture. I'll edit my post so everyone see what going on.

Comment: An example of what you can inject in a view is Orchard. Beside the localizer which they implemented as a delegate (nice one) they also have a resource manager, script manager etc.

Comment: As far as I know, Razor does request views from the dependency resolver. You don't have to call the `DependencyResolver` from within that constructor. However, it is probably still not a good idea to inject dependencies into the view, since in that case the view will be doing more than just viewing.

Comment: It does request views from the DependencyResolver but not the _Layout.cshtml as it seems... And that is the problem... So who creates the _Layout.cshtml?

Comment: @Padel: Create a default constructor in your `WebViewPage<TModel>` and set a breakpoint in it. If the debugger breaks, you'll know who's creating it. It it doesn't break, then your class isn't used and your configuration is wrong.

Comment: @Padel, I'm having exactly the same issue with StructureMap. Did you ever resolve it?